# How to remove single quote(') and double quote(") in url (query string) from zend framwork

Tags: zend-framework

link : www.fixpod.com.au/index.php/?'dsds

i need to  any user add single ' or "" quotes in url its redirect to error page please advice me
i used Zend framwork.

as below link i add single qutes in url but not redirct in 404 page.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid SQL injections? If so, you doing it wrong.

Comment: can you tell which file i changed in zendframwork.

Comment: can you tell me how to redirect in 404 url in zend framwork for example link : http://www.fixpod.com.au/?' or http://www.fixpod.com.au/?" you click any link its need to  redirct in 404 page.any suggation in zend framwork which file i will change?

Comment: No, I can't. Try [this](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/zend-framework-2-programmatically-handle-404-page/)